# How to make a tkinter GUI faster?

Tags: python, tkinter

everybody,

i am currently working on a GUI with tkinter, which consists of a text widget that is supposed to act as an XML code editor. I use tagging to color mark certain keywords like xml tags, but unfortunately this operation is very slow and you can see that the gui thread takes a lot of time to highlight everything. Is there a way to speed this up (e.g. multiple threads that change the gui or something similar)? Or is there a GUI framework that allows to build more responsive guis?

Comment: Hi, please edit your post and add the actual code of what you've been doing. Consider referring to the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the documentation.

Comment: We can't optimize code which we can't see. Please [edit] your question to include  a [mcve]. Please don't paste your entire program, create an example specifically for this question.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of GUI toolkits (including `tkinter`) are not thread-safe; so you should not issue GUI calls from multiple threads.

If you want to know why a program is slow, in general you have to *profile* it. A profiler is a tool that helps you see where a program is spending its time. Python has a built-in profiler in the form of the `cProfile` module. For example, to profile my [`unlock-excel.py`](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/unlock-excel.py) script, I would use the following command:

```
python3 -m cProfile -s cumulative unlock-excel.py ~/foo.xlsm | less
```

It also produces output for `tkinter` programs like [`unlock-excel.pyw`](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/master/unlock-excel.pyw);

```
python3 -m cProfile -s cumulative unlock-excel.pyw
```

In the latter case, `tkinter` calls will show up as e.g. `__init__.py:1281(mainloop)` or `{method 'call' of '_tkinter.tkapp' objects}`.

With this, you should be able to determine if the slowness is in your code or if it happens in `tkinter`.